# Using XPATH to find text that is in a div within a div

Tags: html, css, xml, selenium, xpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<div id="app" class="grid bg-local font-body justify-center" style="background-image: url(&quot;/img/picture.jpg&quot;);"> 
  <div data-v-f7g8b83d=" " data-fruit-code="**I WANT TO GET WHAT'S IN HERE**" class="note relative bg-background items-center select-none w-56 sm:w-64 pb-4" style="transform: rotate(6deg);"/>  
  <div data-v-f7g8b83d=" " data-fruit-code="**I WANT TO GET WHAT'S IN HERE 1**" class="note relative bg-background items-center select-none w-56 sm:w-64 pb-4" style="transform: rotate(6deg);"/>  
  <div data-v-f7g8b83d=" " data-fruit-code="**I WANT TO GET WHAT'S IN HERE 2**" class="note relative bg-background items-center select-none w-56 sm:w-64 pb-4" style="transform: rotate(6deg);"/>  
  <div data-v-f7g8b83d=" " data-fruit-code="**I WANT TO GET WHAT'S IN HERE 3**" class="note relative bg-background items-center select-none w-56 sm:w-64 pb-4" style="transform: rotate(6deg);"/>  
  <div data-v-f7g8b83d=" " data-fruit-code="**I WANT TO GET WHAT'S IN HERE 4**" class="note relative bg-background items-center select-none w-56 sm:w-64 pb-4" style="transform: rotate(6deg);"/> 
</div>
```

I'm trying to build a bot to **scrape** a specific website. I want to be able to get the text that's associated with "data-fruit-code".

I came up with this:

```
//*[@id="app"]/div[2]/div
```

and this:

```
//*[@data-fruit-code]
```

However, both only highlighted the entire div. I feel like I am missing something here. What can I add or how can I fix my existing XPATH command so that it only gets the "data-fruit-code" text?

I tried adding
text() & word() but those did not work for me either.

Here are some of the references I used to get help with this.

https://devhints.io/xpath#class-check

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath

Comment: Hi Robopatchers.  Welcome to StackOverflow.  Nice first question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `data-fruit-code` is called an *attribute* and is selected in XPath via a `@` preceding its name.

There are lots of ways to select the targeted attributes.  Here are two interesting possibilities:

1. This XPath,

   ```
   //@data-fruit-code
   ```

   will select all of the `data-fruit-code` attributes in the document.
2. This XPath,

   ```
   //div[@id="app"]/div/@data-fruit-code
   ```

   will select all `data-fruit-code` attributes on `div` elements whose `div` parents have and `id` attribute value of `app`.

Comment: Oh, this makes a lot of sense now! Thank you so much @kjhuges, this was very informative!

Comment: @kjhuges: Awesome, I just did.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
//div[@data-fruit-code]/@data-fruit-code
```

Output

```
**I WANT TO GET WHAT'S IN HERE**
**I WANT TO GET WHAT'S IN HERE 1**
**I WANT TO GET WHAT'S IN HERE 2**
**I WANT TO GET WHAT'S IN HERE 3**
**I WANT TO GET WHAT'S IN HERE 4**
```

Comment: Why  the extra `[@data-fruit-code]` predicate rather than just `//div/@data-fruit-code`?